# Better condition in java for conditional code

Tags: java, java-8

I want to write code on some conditions as below in java :

```
if(a != null && b != null ){
     // throw new ArithmaticException("some message");
}

if(a == null && b == null ){
    // throw new ArithmaticException("some message");
}
```

Is there a better way to write this in java

Comment: `if((a == null) == (b == null)){ … }` or `if(a == null? b == null: b != null){ … }`

Comment: Or `if(!(a == null ^ b == null))`.

Comment: what if i keep it the way it is for the sake of  readability

Comment: Then, the code looks exactly like you have posted.